# Repeater breaking after first item found and manipulate div tag

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to loop a field within item databound of a repeater however after the first true value it is failing and the sites stops binding the rest of the control

```
 protected void rptPayments_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
     {
         DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
         bool isInArrears = (bool)  drv.Row["isinArrears"];
     }
}
```

The affect is it only prints the first item it finds in the db its value is true but my source of repeater looks for all the values be they true or false.

The `isinArrears` is a boolean field within the db can someone help me out. I also need to change the `<div class="panel panel-default">` div to say success or fail.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptPayments" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptPayments_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<%#Container.ItemIndex %>">

                    <div class="alert-box notice">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="isinArrears" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("isinArrears") %>' />
                            <a><%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("paymentDate")).ToString("MMMM d  yyyy") %>  </a><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse<%#Container.ItemIndex %>" class="<%# GetItemClass(Container.ItemIndex) %>" style="height: auto;">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <!-- <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>-->
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>
                                Payment Agreed: 
                                <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblPaymentsPerMonth" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("agreedPaymentsPerMonth") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>
                                Payment Date:  
                                <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblPayemntDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("paymentDate")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>
                                Payment Due:
                                <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblPaymentDUE" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("paymentDue") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
                                <br />
                                <br />

                            </p>
                            <i class="fa fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" title="Copy to use check-circle-o"></i>
                        </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>
                                Arreas:  
                                <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("isinArrears") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

This is how I am filling in my asp repeater using linq.

```
public List<tblPortalPayment> getUserPayments(Guid recordId)
{
    List <tblPortalPayment> _payments= portalEntities.tblPortalPayments.Where(a=>a.CustomerId== recordId && a.isDeleted==false).ToList();

    return _payments;
}
```

Comment: you're missing quite a bit of code.  care to share the rest of it?

Comment: @NotMe what is it you are require to see

Comment: @NotMe added my getpayments method i dont think i need to show all code for this to be readable question when i Include to much i get said that its to much

Comment: have you inspected the _payments result to see if it actually has more than 1 record?

Comment: @NotMe me yes i have it has six records so it does of varitons of true and false for that elemen t

Comment: @NotMe any ideas on this one?

Comment: honestly, in this situation there's only a couple potential places to look.  The first place is to put a break point on your `return _payments;` and triple check that you are getting more than 1 row back.  Next trim down your repeater until it only emits one of the fields from your result set.  Third, remove everything from your `_itemdatabound` event.  Once you've confirmed it's now emitting all 6 records then start adding stuff back in until you find the source of the problem.

Comment: Also I'd do a view source on the html that's generated to ensure that the elements aren't just being hidden by something in your style sheet.